# JavaScript, onsubmit

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I am trying to understand why onsubmit at Javascript is using an anonymous function to get it value like that:

```
onsubmit = function() {return validForm();}
```

I know that onsubmit is taking a true or false values, but i can't understand how does the anonymous function is necessary to get the value of true or false for the onsubmit event, like this:

```
onsubmit = validForm();
```

I will be very thankful if some one can please help me understand this, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: You can simple `onsubmit = validForm`

Comment: Thank you guys i got it now, have a nice day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A valid assignment would be:

```
onsubmit = validForm;
```

You're assigning the function called validForm as the onsubmit handler. But, when you do this:

```
onsubmit = validForm();
```

You're assigning the *result* of calling the function validForm to the onsubmit handler. Unless validForm is returning a *function*, this won't work.

The reason the anonymous function assignment above works is, it is assigning a *function* to the onsubmit handler -- a function that in turn calls the validForm function when it is called.

Comment: Ah... But you have my upvote because you explained it well with an explicit example.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `validForm` and setting `onsubmit` to its return value. In example:

```
function foo () {
    return "hi";
}

onsubmit = foo() // eq to onsubmit = "hi";

onsubmit = foo // onsubmit now has the same function as foo
```